# "Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character" running v4l2-ctl

Tags: raspberry-pi, v4l2, iterm

Using iTerm, I'm SSHing into my raspberry pi (raspbian) to control a home security system I've setup.

I need to change the focus of my camera, so I'm running `v4l2-ctl -c focus_absolute=0` on my terminal.

I've been doing this for weeks, and it hasn't given me any issues. Today, when running the command I've started getting the following error:

```
VIDIOC_S_EXT_CTRLS: failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
focus_absolute: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

What could be causing it to suddenly be throwing this error? I've been running the exact same command for weeks without a problem.

Comment: Did you figure out what was it?

Comment: I have not. The command randomly works, then doesn't. I haven't figured out what's causing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer in here: https://askubuntu.com/a/388045/814834. Turns out that when, for example, the camera's `auto_exposure` setting is set to `1` (`true`) then, whenever you modify settings that are controlled by that "automatic" setting, in this case the `absolute_exposure`, you will get that useless error because you have to first change the `auto_exposure` to `0` (`false`) in order to change the settings controlled by it

Comment: Indeed, this "useless error" as you call it probably deserves to be improved.  I couldn't find information on how to submit patches or bug reports, so... if someone knows, or if one of the maintainers sees this, it'd be a nice thing to do.